# Cannot unload project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, csproj, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution with a project file that I need to modify as text (i.e. the XML). This is done by right clicking on the project and selecting `Unload Project`, then right clicking on it again and selecting `Edit Project.csproj`. However, this does not work on all projects. Sometimes I get the message

```
The operation could not be completed
```

I want to know why this message sometimes appears (i.e. what is it about my project / solution configuration that could bring this about) and whether there is another way to edit the .csproj within Visual Studio (if I try and close the solution then open the .csproj file Visual Studio just opens the solution again).

Comment: I got this problem today, really annoying

Comment: I found a workaround to this problem. In Source Control Explorer, find the .csproj file and right click -> Advanced -> View With... -> XML (Text) Editor